# how to grab subitems with checkboxes in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

I am currently trying to grab all the subitems from one column from every checked listviewitem, and display them in the richtextbox, but I am not sure how to do it. This is my current code.

I am also trying to do this in the ItemChecked Event.

```
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            if (listView1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                richTextBox2.Text = listView1.CheckedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;

            }
        }
```

I thought this would work but apparently not. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the content of the textbox in each loop. Try appending the text with `+=`. You also need to pick the correct item

```
richTextBox2.Text = String.Empty;
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    if (item.Checked)
    {
        richTextBox2.Text += item.SubItems[1].Text + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

You could also write this with a LINQ expression and [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx)

```
richTextBox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    from item in listView1.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>()
    where item.Checked
    select item.SubItems[1].Text);
```

Comment: That works! But when I check just one item it writes both into the RichTextBox and keeps writing if I decheck it. I am doing this all in the ItemChecked Event aswell I forgot to mention.

Comment: When using the LINQ expression I get this error

Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection'.  'Where' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'item'.

Comment: @IanLundberg, fixed both issues, in the first example, clear the text first, before the loop. In the second, `.OfType<ListViewItem>()` converts the collection items to the right type.